# How to update url without losing input data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this option selector which updates url adding `?type=size`, type depends on option selected. I use $_GET to then get the data from url.

The problem is, after entering value in inputs (name, price, etc) before, then on selection part the page refreshes and the input data I entered before is gone.

[image]

```
    <label>Type</label>
    <select name="type" onchange="location = this.value;">
        <option>Select...</option>
        <option value="?type=size">Size</option>
        <option value="?type=weight">Weight</option>
        <option value="?type=dimension">Dimension</option>
    </select>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How and why are you changing the url?  (Emphasis on why) Just submit it all at once. Or, if you need to change some options, do an Ajax call.

Comment: @TimMorton selected option there is div that needs to be displayed. For example, if I select size, with `$_GET` I return an input "size", if weight is selected, then it returns input "weight".

Comment: This is crying out for client-side Javascript. Add an onChange listener, maybe perform a background AJAX request and display / update your div.

Comment: You are currently simply overwriting the location with whatever the selected option’s value is, so of course you lose all other GET parameters. If this select field and the other input fields you have shown are in the same form - then simply submit that form instead.